# Using GIT to push my code into remote by creating new branch - all the steps please

Tags: git, github

Im trying to create a new branch and push all my changes into the remote branch..
My steps:
git branch  (shows *master)

should i, **add --a** and **git commit -m "MAR/100: Description"**  and  **git push** before

git checkout -n MAR/100       (MAR/100 is my new directory name)
git push origin MAR/100   so will all my new changes go into the remote Branch?

Im confused please someone give me full steps and flow to push my current code that I have on my System (Local, also explain ) to a new branch, and to get the changes in the master when any new updates are made to the master!!

Comment: sorry its **git checkout -b MAR/100**

Comment: you should read the git book then retry. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: What ezain said, or at least go through a git tutorial. Also, a graphical client might be helpful at the beginning.

Comment: @CptBartender Using a Git GUI when learning Git is the surest way to get confused, IMO. Start at the command line, then move to a GUI if it makes your workflow easier.

Comment: @Jubobs I guess that's up to personal preference, and what GUI we're talking about... From my experience, some are confusing as hell, but some actually can be helpful, it's just that as a git newbie one doesn't know which one's which until it's too late :P

Answer (score 0):

To get your code into the branch and then push to remote:

```
git checkout -b MAR/100
git add -a *
git commit -m 'Mar/100: description'
git push origin MAR/100
```

To fetch changes from the master and merge it with your local branch:

```
git checkout MAR/100
git fetch origin master
git merge master
```

The [awesome git tutorial here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-fetch) might help you towards a solid understanding of these concepts. I've linked you to the part on `git fetch` but the whole thing including [this section](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches) on using branches might be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you

1.-Create the branch on your local machine and switch in this branch

```
git checkout -b MAR/100
```

2.-add staging area

```
git add -A
```

3.-Make commit

```
git commit -m 'your message'
```

4.-make push

```
git push -u origin MAR/100
```

5.-(Optional)Make pull if you have collaborators and get the full code on your repository, you will see "already up to date" if you have the code updated.

```
git pull
```

Comment: why should i add **git pull**? also by using command 4 will that create a new branch MAR/100 in remote??

Comment: @Adithya.K i updated my answer, but is for check that you have the last version of your code from your Remote repository to your local repository, and no when you make git push you send your local branch to your Remote repository , you dont need to create a branch in Remote repository. greetings.